# Is there a way to find which txt file a string comes from with javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, processing, p5.js

I have a randomly generated sentence from 16 txt files and I'm trying to reverse engineer the function so that I could see which sentence corresponds to which txt file. I'm using if/else right now but it's very slow and I'm wondering if there's another way to do this? I'm using p5.js and rita.js libraries.

```
var lines, markov, data1, data2, data3, data4, data5, data6, data7,  x = 160, y = 240;
var mySound;
let myCanvas;
var randomImageLocation;
let img = [];
var index = 0;
var typed="";
var ellipsecolor = 44;
var timer = 10;
var nextTime = timer;
let button;
let anotherStrata;
let myfi;
let datta1;

function preload() {
  data1 = loadStrings('assets/newtxt/1.txt');
  data2 = loadStrings('assets/newtxt/2.txt');
  data3 = loadStrings('assets/newtxt/three.txt');
  data4 = loadStrings('assets/newtxt/four.txt');
  data5 = loadStrings('assets/newtxt/five.txt');
  data6 = loadStrings('assets/newtxt/six.txt');
  data7 = loadStrings('assets/newtxt/seven.txt');
  data8 = loadStrings('assets/newtxt/8.txt');
  data9 = loadStrings('assets/newtxt/9.txt');
  data10 = loadStrings('assets/newtxt/ten.txt');
  data11 = loadStrings('assets/newtxt/11.txt');
  data12 = loadStrings('assets/newtxt/12.txt');
  data13 = loadStrings('assets/newtxt/13.txt');
  data14 = loadStrings('assets/newtxt/14.txt');
  data15 = loadStrings('assets/newtxt/15.txt');
  data16 = loadStrings('assets/newtxt/16.txt');
  img[0] = loadImage("img/img0.png");
  img[1] =  loadImage("img/img1.png");
  bg = loadImage("img/background.jpg");
}


function setup() {
  let createcanvas = createCanvas(window.innerWidth /2 , window.innerHeight - 150);
  createcanvas.parent('mycanvas');
  bg = loadImage("img/background.jpg");
  textFont('avenir');
  textSize(20 + (mouseX / width)*72);
  frameRate(30);
   fill('beige');
   lines = ["click to place your order!"];

  // create a markov model w' n=4
  markov = new RiMarkov(8);

  datta1 = data1.join(' ');
  datta2 = data2.join(' ');
  datta3 = data3.join(' ');
  datta4 = data4.join(' ');
  datta5 = data5.join(' ');
  datta6 = data6.join(' ');
  datta7 = data7.join(' ');
  datta8 = data8.join(' ');
  datta9 = data9.join(' ');
  datta10 = data10.join(' ');
  datta11 = data11.join(' ');
  datta12 = data12.join(' ');
  datta13 = data13.join(' ');
  datta14 = data14.join(' ');
  datta15 = data15.join(' ');
  datta16 = data16.join(' ');
  // load text into the model
  markov.loadText(data1.join(' '));
  markov.loadText(data2.join(' '));
  markov.loadText(data3.join(' '));
  markov.loadText(data4.join(' '));
  markov.loadText(data5.join(' '));
  markov.loadText(data6.join(' '));
  markov.loadText(data7.join(' '));
  markov.loadText(data8.join(' '));
  markov.loadText(data9.join(' '));
  markov.loadText(data10.join(' '));
  markov.loadText(data11.join(' '));
  markov.loadText(data12.join(' '));
  markov.loadText(data13.join(' '));
  markov.loadText(data14.join(' '));
  markov.loadText(data15.join(' '));
  markov.loadText(data16.join(' '));
  drawText();
}
function ellipsee(){
   if (millis() > nextTime){
    ellipsecolor +=1;
    nextTime = millis() + timer;
    }
}
function draw(){
  image(anotherStrata, 0, 0)
  line(mouseX, mouseY, pmouseX, pmouseY);
  translate (mouseX, mouseY);
  fill(ellipsecolor);
  var value = random(0, 600);
  ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 0.4, 0.4);
}
function drawText() {
  background(bg);
  textSize(20 + (mouseX / width)*33);
  myfi = text(lines.join(' '), 50, 201, 400, 530);
}

function scrollToBottom(id){
   var div = document.getElementById(id);
   div.scrollTop = div.scrollHeight - div.clientHeight;
}



//this function

function findTxtFile() {

  var pf1 = datta1.includes(lines);
  var pf2 = datta2.includes(lines);
  var pf3 = datta3.includes(lines);
  var pf4 = datta4.includes(lines);
  var pf5 = datta5.includes(lines);
  var pf6 = datta6.includes(lines);
  var pf7 = datta7.includes(lines);
  var pf8 = datta8.includes(lines);
  var pf9 = datta9.includes(lines);
  var pf10 = datta10.includes(lines);
  var pf11 = datta11.includes(lines);
  var pf12 = datta12.includes(lines);
  var pf13 = datta13.includes(lines);
  var pf14 = datta14.includes(lines);
  var pf15 = datta15.includes(lines);
  var pf16 = datta16.includes(lines);

 let newa;
  if (pf1==true){
      newa = createA("assets/newtxt/1.txt", lines);
  }
  if (pf2==true){
      newa = createA("assets/newtxt/2.txt", lines);
  }
  if (pf3==true){
      newa = createA("assets/newtxt/three.txt", lines);
  }
  if (pf4==true){
     newa = createA("assets/newtxt/four.txt", lines);
  }
  if (pf5==true){
      newa = createA("assets/newtxt/five.txt", lines);
  }
  if (pf6==true){
      newa = createA("assets/newtxt/six.txt", lines);
  }
  if (pf7==true){
      newa = createA("assets/newtxt/seven.txt", lines);
  }
  if (pf8==true){
      newa = createA("assets/newtxt/8.txt", lines);
  }
  if (pf9==true){
     newa = createA("assets/newtxt/9.txt", lines);
  }
  if (pf10==true){
      newa = createA("assets/newtxt/ten.txt", lines);
  }
  if (pf11==true){
      newa = createA("assets/newtxt/11.txt", lines);
  }
  if (pf12==true){
      newa = createA("assets/newtxt/12.txt", lines);
  }
  if (pf13==true){
      newa = createA("assets/newtxt/13.txt", lines);
  }
  if (pf14==true){
     newa = createA("assets/newtxt/14.txt", lines);
  }
  if (pf15==true){
      newa = createA("assets/newtxt/15.txt", lines);
  }
  if (pf16==true){
      newa = createA("assets/newtxt/16.txt", lines);
  }

  newa.style('font-family', 'monospace');
  newa.style('color', 'green');
  newa.style('font-size', '12pt');
  newa.parent('consolog');
  newa.class('pulse');

  let newb = createElement('br');
  newb.parent('consolog');
  scrollToBottom('consolog');
  }
function mouseClicked() {
  typed="";
  x = 100;
  y = 220;
  lines = markov.generateSentences(1);
  drawText();
  mySound.play();
  anotherStrata.clear();
  findTxtFile();
}
function mouseReleased(){
           index = index + 1;
          if (index == img.length){
              index = index - img.length;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In p5.js [`match()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/match) respectively [`matchAll()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/matchAll) can be used to find occurrences of a [Regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) or a string in a text.

See the example:

```js
function setup() {
    createCanvas(400, 200);
}

function draw() {
    var string = 'Hello World!';
    
    var str1 = match(string, "World");
    var str2 = match(string, "Dog");

    textSize(50);
    text(str1 ? str1 : "not found", 20, 70);
    text(str2 ? str2 : "not found", 20, 130);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/p5.js"></script>
```